# Using visual node cause express to not serve static files

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2012, express

I had a working project but I decided to try Visual Node (http://www.visualnode.info/readme) in order to work with node.js in Visual Studio environment.

For some reason, that line doesn't affect express to serve static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
```

When trying to:

```
 res.sendfile('client/views/index.html');
```

The engine searches the file under wrong path:

```
404 Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Windows\system32\client\views\index.html'
```

The question is where `'C:\Windows\system32\'` came from ?

Instead of that, there should be my project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));`

is a a middleware adapter so that express will automatically serve static files from the `client` folder (using `__dirname`) to establish the current local directory as a reference.

When you use

`res.sendfile('client/views/index.html');`

Node and express will use the current local directory + path to serve the file. However, it appears that when you're using Visual Node, it's not correctly setting the local path to where the application is stored, so the path is unfortunately set to the `system32` directory.

You can see how your application should work if you switch to the directory where your application is stored and run:

```
> cd c:\dev\greatwebapp
> node app.js
```

*(substitute the real names of course)*

You'll see something like:

```
Express server listening on port 3000
```

Then, you should be able to navigate a browser to one of your routes/paths and the file should be displayed correctly. It seems like it might be an issue with Visual Node: http://redgatesupport.red-gate.com/entries/25428576-Working-Directory-Issues.

To work around the issue, you could:

`res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');`

Comment: Hopefully they'll get it fix. Thanks for the workaround solution !